# .htaccess not acting as suspected

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I'm using CI and WAMP on a Windows 7 machine.  In my Application folder of the site I have a `.htaccess` file with the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

This was copied and modified [CodeIgniter User Guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html).  And I made sure the rewrite_module (didn't it used to be mod_rewrite?) was active and restarted WAMP.  In my controller, I have the following:

```
<?php

class Forum extends CI_Controller
{
public function index()
{
    $data['title'] = "Card Forums";
    $this->load->view('Header', $data);
    $this->load->model('forumdb');
    $data['sections'] = $this->forumdb->getSections();
    $this->load->view('Home', $data);
    $this->load->view('Footer');
}

public function site()
{
    $data['title'] = "Card Forums - Site";
    $this->load->view('Header', $data);
    $data['section'] = "Site";
    $this->load->view('Forum', $data);
    $this->load->view('Footer');
}
}
```

When I go to `localhost/forum` it does exactly as I want.  But when I try to go to `localhost/forum/site` it is displaying the following:

---

## Not Found

The requested URL /forum/site was not found on this server.

---

In the view `Forum` I have:

```
<?php echo $section; ?>
```

Which is only supposed to display the the variable right now because I want to make sure I'm accessing the page first (just started writing this site Friday).  When I try `localhost/forum/index.php/site` it's giving me a 404 error.

I have a feeling I'm missing something VERY simple here and it's bugging me.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try using a ?$1 instead of /$1

Comment: Nope, that didn't do it.  Same results both ways I try the URL.

Comment: have you restarted the server?

Comment: After activating rewrite_module?  I restarted WAMP, but not my computer.  Think I should try that?

Comment: You just need to restart wamp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an updated .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

In your /forum/config folder find the config.php and change this line

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

To

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Then as you mentioned you can use function like `base_url('css/site.css');`

One thing I generally do with this type of htaccess file is add an entry for a folder called public so in my case it would look like this.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Then I have all my assests in the public folder, and I don't need to keep adding exceptions to my htaccess file.

Comment: That didn't work either.  I'm still getting the `Not Found` error.

Comment: Have you put Codeigniter into a folder? wamp/www/somefolder/ for example?

Comment: Also, I just noticed you say that the .htaccess file is in the application folder, it goes above that folder.

Comment: Yep.  My directory is C:\wamp\www\forum\... Inside Forum is the Application, System and CSS folder.  I have the .htaccess located at C:\wamp\www\forum\application\.htaccess.

Comment: move the .htaccess file to the forum folder, not the application folder. I'm sure I've done that before :-)

Comment: You may also want to search the config/config.php and change `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';` to `$config['index_page'] = '';` if you are remove the index.php bit of the url

Comment: The reason I had it in the application folder was because as I had copied it from CI User Guide, putting it in the Forum folder caused it to simply go straight to the WAMP home page, not my site.  But now that I removed the `/` like you suggested, it works in that it goes to the page I want it to...BUT now my CSS link is broken, so I'll have to fix that.

Comment: I recommend autoloading the url helper, for any links or assets you want to use you can make use of the site_url(); function I believe. The CodeIgniter documentaion is awesome once you give it a read through.

Comment: Well I was using `base_url()` as that returns `http://localhost/Forum` (`site_url()` returns `http://localhost/Forum/index.php`).  My link was `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/site.css" />`, and it worked before getting the `.htaccess` to work.

Comment: Sorry yes you're right about the function.. base_url('css/site.css'); is the way to go, I mentioned above about checking your config/config.php file find this `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';` change it to `$config['index_page'] = '';`, you may need to change this line of the .htaccess file `RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)` to `RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css)`

Comment: Simply adding the `|css` fixed it.  I highly appreciate it.

Comment: I've tweaked my answer a little more to kind of offer some more understanding. Thanks for accepting the answer, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

For WAMP (and most other environemnts for my CI projects), I've had most luck with the following additional flags in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Also, Check your `uri_protocol` in `config.php`. I've had most luck with setting it to `PATH_INFO` instead of `AUTO`.

One last thing to try: CI sometimes detects the `base_url` wrong in WAMP environments. Either define your `base_url` in `config.php`.